# How to convert 'Mon Jul 22 14:51:34 IST 2019' into '2019-07-22'

Tags: mysql, sql

"How to convert 'Mon Jul 22 14:51:34 IST 2019' into '2019-07-22'."

Comment: Fix your data!  Don't store date/time values as strings!

Comment: *"Fix your data! Don't store date/time values as strings! "* very true @GordonLinoff But i assume the topicstarter already has a running application(s) on this table which also needs to be changed aswell? But i totally agree DATETIME/DATE datatype should have been used. Topicstarter see [STR_TO_DATE(str,format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), one problem might be the IST in the string to convert it correct then you might need to use `CONVERT_TZ()`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE('Mon Jul 22 14:51:34 IST 2019','%a %b %d %H:%i:%s IST %Y')) x;
+------------+
| x          |
+------------+
| 2019-07-22 |
+------------+
```

Comment: What if instead of IST its MST? how we make it generic?